# How to have hover and click events on images that curve over one another with transparent backgrounds?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have multiple curved images (boxes labeled `1`, `2`, and `3` in the image) with transparent backgrounds (2's transparent background shown with dotted lines in the image) in the same area of the page that each have their own hover and click events. I positioned them using `position: absolute;`, but due to the transparent background, the last added image is the only one having its hover/click activated.

Is there anything I can do to allow the `1` and `3` images to get hover and click events?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). You'll need to combine all three images into one and set it as a background-image for an HTML element. You can then use background-position to manipulate how what is displayed.